# What did Rabbi Yannai understand about 'Mi Ha-ish'?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, lashon-hara-slander

The Midrash [[Leviticus R. 16:2]](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.34.13-15?lang=bi&with=Vayikra%20Rabbah&lang2=en&p3=Vayikra_Rabbah.16&lang3=bi) says:

> A peddler used to make the rounds of the towns near Sepphoris, crying out: "Who wishes to buy the potion for a long life?" and drawing large crowds around him. Rabbi Yannai... said to him: Come here and sell it to me... The peddler... brought out the Book of Psalms and showed him the passage:
>
> Who is the man who desires life, and loves many days, that he may see good? Keep your tongue from evil, and your lips from speaking guile.  Depart from evil, and do good. Seek peace and pursue it. [﻿Ps. 34:13-15]
>
> Rabbi Yannai said: All my life have I been reading this passage, but did not know how it was to be explained, until this peddler came and made it clear!

It is not clear to me what "explanation" Rabbi Yannai heard.  The biblical text is very clear and needs no further elaboration.  Is it that the peddler's brilliant advertising idea for selling copies of the Book of Psalms brought the teaching to life?  A bit weak.  Anything else in the Sources?

Comment: ArtScroll’s edition of the Midrash indeed quotes an Achron who says that the peddler was bringing it to life.

Comment: See kli yakar  ..https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%93

Comment: He gives a pshat pashut from the Sefer Haakeda that from the rochel you understand the changing from lashon nistar to lashon nochach, as the rochel made. And a second pshat more drush